# Subclassing a file object to "fake" it as an iterable - Python

Tags: python, oop, file-io, iterable, python-collections

My thought was to get rid of how users are constantly using `seek(0)` to reset the text file reading.

So instead I've tried to create a `MyReader` that's an `collections.Iterator` and then using `.reset()` to replace `seek(0)` and then it continues from where it last yielded by retaining a `self.iterable` object.

```
class MyReader(collections.Iterator):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.iterable = self.__iterate__()

    def __iterate__(self):
        with open(self.filename) as fin:
            for line in fin:
                yield line.strip()

    def __iter__(self):
        for line in self.iterable:
            yield line

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.iterable)

    def reset(self): 
        self.iterable = self.__iterate__()
```

The usage would be something like:

```
$ cat english.txt
abc
def
ghi
jkl

$ python

>>> data = MyReader('english.txt')
>>> print(next(data))
abc
>>> print(next(data))
def
>>> data.reset()
>>> print(next(data))
abc
```

My question is **does this already exist in Python-verse somewhere?** Esp. if there's already a native object that does something like this, I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel =)

If it doesn't exist? **Does the object look a little unpythonic?** Since it says it's an iterator but the true Iterator is actually the `self.iterable` and the other functions are wrapping around it to do "resets".

Comment: Did you even test your snippet? It is totally not executable. Missing `self` in `__init__`, `filename` in `__iterate__` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry I was abstracting from a bigger class. Now it should work.

Comment: File-like objects already do something like this --you get the same output if you do `data = open('english.txt')` and `data.seek(0)` instead of `data.reset()`. What does using `data.reset()` instead of `data.seek(0)` buys you?

Comment: Ah so instead of `Iterator` I could have inherit from `File`? Hmmm, the object does many more things though =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on what is your real situation. Let's say if you just want to get rid of `file.seek(0)`, it can be simple:

```
class MyReader:
    def __init__(self, filename, mode="r"):
        self.file = open(filename, mode)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        self.file.seek(0)
        for line in self.file:
            yield line.strip()

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()
```

You can even use it like a normal context manager:

```
with MyReader("a.txt") as a:
    for line in a:
        print(line)
    for line in a:
        print(line)
```

output:

```
sdfas
asdf
asd
fas
df
asd
f
sdfas
asdf
asd
fas
df
asd
f
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of criticisms of your `MyReader` class. I *was* going to post an alternative that's a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) but Sraw beat me to it. ;)

You shouldn't use names that start and end with double underscores like `__iterate__`. Such names are essentially reserved for the language implementors, and if an official `__iterate__` magic method is added to the language your code will break. If you want a private method, you could name it `_iterate`.

There is a little problem with that `__iterate__` method: its `with` block is only exited when the file has been completely read for the current `self.iterable`, so if the `MyReader` instance gets reset then you have an old open file sitting around, consuming a file descriptor. Sure, it'll get closed eventually, when the program exits (or you delete the `MyReader` instance), but it's messy IMHO.

Also, I'm not totally happy with the `yield line.strip()`. Sure, it's convenient most of the time when you're reading a text file, but in some cases the caller may want to look at any leading or trailing white space, and you've taken that option away from them.

BTW, that `__iter__` method is redundant: your class still does what its supposed to do if you eliminate that method.

Comment: BTW, with `__next__`, Python automatically infers `__iter__` ?